# How to identify and target a form element?

Tags: 7, forms, debugging

A similar question has been asked before: [How do you identify a form element?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5605/how-do-you-identify-a-form-element)

I am using the Devel module and `dpm($form)` outputs the object nicely:

[image: screen]

But I can't set/change the default value of a custom field. How do I target set the default value to 164 in this case?

```
$form['question_node_form']['field_points']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = 164;
```

The above does not work and the points_field is blank.

EDIT (complete function):

```
function custom2_form_question_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
    drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
    dpm($form);
    $form['question_node_form']['field_points']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = 164;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you sure you are declaring the form_alter function to take the $form array by reference? (`hook_form_alter(&$form)` ?)

Comment: Hey Ayesh! Thx for your suggestion. Ive added the full function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the explicit `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` for a start so `$form_id` will never be anything except `question_node_form`.

However the problem is you are trying to target a child of the form array. The top level array **is already** `question_node_form`. Your code should look like this:

```
function custom2_form_question_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_points']['und']['0']['value']['#default_value'] = 164;
}
```

*Debugging removed for clarity. Noticed we removed `['question_node_form']`.*

Also note you can't pass `$form_id` by reference (not that it matters) as it can't be changed.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7

Comment: Nitpick: you _can_ pass `$form_id` by reference, it can be changed, it's just that the calling function doesn't do anything with the changes so it's a bit pointless doing so

Comment: Thanks Clive. Really? You can change it? Sounds scary!